# Use Long Data Types in Ratings method in mllib recommendation model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am having an rdd which has movie ids as long as 17 digits which i need to feed in the `org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating` method but the method accepts movie ids as Integers only , also as per my understanding this is an issue raised in [Spark_forums]https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2465 also but the status says "won't fix" over there.

I am looking for a way around to achieve this without any collisions.

`val ratings = rawRatings.map { case Array(user, movie, rating) => Rating(user.toInt, movie.toInt, rating.toDouble) }`

sample movie id= 34803284448484840

Answer (score 0):

If your id range fits in an Integer, you can create a mapping

```
val idToIndexMapping: RDD[(Long, Int)] = movieIdsRdd.zipWithIndex().cache()
```

and use this mapping to replace the values in your data. Once the recommendation is generated you can reverse lookup the original id to serve the recommendation.